# How to get html dom object of a MMC snapin node using MMC automation object model

Tags: c#, winforms, window, mmc

I am using automation object model for an existing mmc file and just trying to traverse all nodes of it and I am able to do so.

My query is : how can I get the access of html dom object of a particular node . A html page is present in result pane of a node, I want to get access of that so that I can perform some automation on that form.

Below is the link I am using for MMC automation object model.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa815049(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa815049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I found that if OCX control is in result view of any node, then "view object -> control object property" returns the automation interface supplied by the control in the result view.

However, if result view is HTML view then how to get the automation interface of that result view.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer :)

We can get the dom handle of a web browser control inside a windows application, after getting the dom, we can perform any action on that html page.
below is the KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q249232